# Can I store data from an iBeacon?

Tags: ibeacon

I'm hoping to create some sort of attendance register by using iBeacons device. I was wondering if it's possible to hook it up to some kind of database to store which devices have passed it?

From what I have found there isn't a lot of documentation about how to store information in the iBeacon device.

Feel free to link anything interesting and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible and it is a very common part of building beacon applications.    The typical approach is to do the following:

Make a mobile app that:

1. Generates a unique device identifier on first run, for later passing to a server.  Send this to the server via a web service call along with name, email,  and any other info you want to collect to identify the user.
2. Detects beacons, passing the beacon identifier on first detection to a web service along with the device identifier from (1)
3. Optionally store the detections in a debice-local persistent data store, in case connectivity is notvavailable at the time of detection so records can be sent to the server later.

Make a server side app that:

1. Has a database that stores beacon detevtions tied to a mobile device identifier, along with a timestamp.
2. Has a database table that assigns meaningful location info to unique beacon identifiers.
3. Exposes a web service to record detection records sent by the mobile app.
4. Exposes a web service to register a new device identifier and tie it to user info like name, email, etc.
5. Add additional logic and perhaps web UI to show the results of specific devices being in beacon-specific places at specific times.

Building an app that does this can vary quite a bit depending on the specific use case.  This is why it does not lend itself to cookie cutter solutions easily linked to on the internet.